# how to to optimize the choice of a rectangular box - PHP

Tags: php, math, optimization, multidimensional-array, mathematical-optimization

Calculation of boxes / Volume / Size
I need to put `m` boxes of `n` different sizes inside another rectangular box!

What is the calculation to obtain the smallest box (with the lowest volume possible) based on the `m` boxes of `n` different sizes?

I know the size of the boxes m, and also know how many are.
Keep in mind that for example:

two boxes with 3 x 3 x 3

only better organized in a box 6 x 3 x 3

and the formula works well:

`sum of the smallest measure` X `the largest measure` X `the other major measure`

Another example is two boxes:

`4 X 5 X 7`

`6 X 8 X 2`

sum of the smallest measure = (4 + 2) X (8) X (7)

However, when we have 10 boxes for example, this does not work at all!
How to organize, and what is the volume of the smallest possible box based on the dimensions of the boxes I have?

I do not know if this question can only be answered with basic tools (I tried via optimization (Derivative) and I could not)

I need to make a calculation via PHP from mailboxes! And I can not solve the problem Mathematically before transforming into code

I don't have problems with PHP code, i have problems with Math, i don`t know how to solve this problem with the best way possible!

I have used the code below, but as explained, it will not work for a lot of boxes, only for 2 or 3.

```
$length = 0;
$height = 0;
$width = 0;

foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
    for ($quantity = 0; $quantity < $product['quantity']; $quantity ++) { 
        $length = $length + (float) $product['dimension'][0];
    }

    if($product['dimension'][1] > $height) {
        $height = (float) $product['dimension'][1];
    }

    if($product['dimension'][2] > $width) {
        $width = (float) $product['dimension'][2];
    }
}

$box = ($length . ' x '. $height . ' x '. $width);
```

Comment: that's a [NP-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) right there, breh. You're gonna have to try it with brute forcing.

Comment: This is called 3d packing. There are algorithms for this (much better than brute force suggested before), but nothing simple. And they are inherently mathematically oriented.